# Asymmetrical (five-parameter) logistic dose-response curve in Python

Tags: python, statistics, logistic-regression

I am trying to calculate the the 5 parameters - min, max, hill slope, logEC50 and asymmetric value from a list of dose, response data. Are there any python packages that perform this calculations or any guidance on how i can compute these values would be helpful